# How to minimize and maximize in Electron.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I have made three custom buttons for close, maximize, and minimize. My function for the close button is working but I have no idea about the maximize and minimize buttons! Actually, I don't really need the maximize button, because my focus is on the minimize button in Electron.js!

I have searched a lot on the internet, but mine is not working anyway!

Plz, help me!

```
<div class="ctrl-box">
<div class="exit" onclick="window.top.close()">×</div>
<div class="minimize">‒</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimize:

```
document.getElementById('minimize').addEventListener('click', () => {
        remote.getCurrentWindow().minimize()
    })
```

Add the above line to your js file.

In the html change

```
<div class="minimize">‒</div>
```

to

```
<div class="minimize" id="minimize>‒</div>
```

Maximize:

For maximizing, you'll have to set the property max-height and max-width of the window in main.js

```
let window = new BrowserWindow({
    //other properties
    maxheight: 720,
    maxwidth: 1366,
    maximizable: true,
    })
```

In the html change

```
<div class="maximize">‒</div>
```

to

```
<div class="maximize" id="maximize>‒</div>
```

After that, add this to your js file of the window.

```
 document.getElementById('maximize').addEventListener('click', () => {
            remote.getCurrentWindow().maximize()
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I worked a lot more on it, but unfortunately nothing changed! I really don't know what causes this problem!

Comment: you'll have to create a new javascript file, example index.js. Then add the above code to the file. In the html, inside body tag, add <script type='type/script src="./index.js" ></script>. The index.js file must be in the same folder as html file.

Comment: Thanks again! but unfortunately, it is not working at all! I'll make another project! Maybe something is not working properly! Tnx buddy